# Octave - How can I use pararrayfun with a file in input?

Tags: loops, parallel-processing, octave

I am a new Octave user. My Octave version is 4.4.1.
I need help on how to use the parallel package.
I have a function `modele_file` that takes in as input a class structure that contains the path to files. I have to load that 'mat' files (see the code below). 
**The problem is that octave indicates that my entry is not defined.**

I would be grateful if someone can help me find what is missing in my code

```matlab
files = dir('./../data/*.mat');
[row col] = size(files);

for k = 1:1000
    name{k} = getfield(files, {k,1}, 'name');
end


fun_str = @(stg) strcat("./../data/", stg) ;
vec_name = arrayfun(fun_str, name) ;
vec_result = arrayfun(fun_str,  repmat({"result/"}, row,1)) ;

a = [vec_name, vec_result'] ;
struct_info = cell2struct(a, {"name", "result"}, 1);

solution = pararrayfun(nproc, modele_file, struct_info)
```

Here an example of my function :

```
function modele = modele_file(info_struct)
  file = info_struct{1} ;
  path = info_struct{2} ; 

  load(strcat(file)) ;
  modele.X = zeros(2,2) ; 
  save('file.mat', 'modele') ;
```

Although my function is able to work. My priority is to launch my function, I do not specifically need it to register in an object.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the definition of modele_file? Please create a MCVE

Comment: does your code work with normal arrayfun?

Comment: My function `model_file` return a structure for an other function.

With the function arrayfun is not working too.